# refactoring postgres join vs except

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, postgresql-9.4

I'm trying to refactor one of my queries and I'm just not doing something quite right.

I would like to combine two queries and make one, but I'm confused on how it works with a LEFT JOIN.

> All QuizMasters who have a state of "active"

**Minus (-)**

> QuizMasters who have an "active" event on a given day (not all QuizMasters have events only ~25%).

**Definitions**

> - **Events** store `start_at` dow/wday for a given event, eg Monday-Sunday (albeit as a DateTime, only the wday and time are relevant).
> - **Events** and **QuizMasters** have states which are either *"active"* or not.

## Old query (which data is correct)

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, email
FROM quiz_masters
WHERE quiz_masters.state = 'active' # (175 rows)

EXCEPT

SELECT first_name, last_name, email
FROM quiz_masters
LEFT JOIN events ON events.quiz_master_id = quiz_masters.id
WHERE quiz_masters.state = 'active'
AND EXTRACT(dow FROM events.start_at::timestamp::date) = 3 AND events.state = 'active'
GROUP BY first_name, last_name, email # (- 20 rows)
```

Total of 155 rows match the query.

## Combined query which doesn't work

I would like to combine them into something like:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, email
FROM quiz_masters
LEFT JOIN events ON events.quiz_master_id = quiz_masters.id
WHERE quiz_masters.state = 'active'
AND events.quiz_master_id IS null
OR (EXTRACT(dow FROM events.start_at::timestamp::date) <> 3 AND events.state = 'active')
GROUP BY first_name, last_name, email
```

144 Rows (missing 11 rows)

But I'm not sure how to keep all the rows from some `quiz_masters` who are active but have no event whatsoever.  It still removes them.  Maybe I need some other kind of join?

Comment: An `except` can typically be re-written as an `not exists` condition.

Comment: mayby in missing rows condition `(extract ....)` is false AND rows in events exists ? You current where is `(quiz_masters.state = 'active'
AND events.quiz_master_id IS null) OR (EXTRACT ...)` i.e. _no rows in events_ OR (dow<>3 and events.state=active)

Comment: BTW `... left join events on ... where events. ...` is wrong. It is actually `inner join` even if you performs the `events.quiz_master_id IS null` check.

Comment: Is there any records in the `quiz_masters` where `quiz_masters.state = 'active'` but which have no corresponding records in the `events` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first query you exclude all events that are active on Wednesday, so inactive events on any day are included. In the combined query you include all events that are active on any day but Wednesday and no inactive events whatsoever. That's your 11 rows difference.

This should get you back to 155 rows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT first_name, last_name, email
FROM quiz_masters
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT quiz_master_id AS id, state
    FROM events
    WHERE EXTRACT(dow FROM events.start_at::timestamp) = 3
    AND events.state = 'active') ev USING (id)
WHERE quiz_masters.state = 'active'
AND ev.state IS NULL;
```

Apparently you have multiple entries for your quiz masters, but rather than doing a `GROUP BY` you should select `DISTINCT` rows. `GROUP BY` should only be used with aggregate functions.

Comment: That doesn't quite work.  It returns 82 rows instead of 155 ;-(  Not all quiz_masters have an event and I think it's removing those once the AND NOT is added?

Comment: Can you **edit** your question and give table definitions and write in natural language what data you want to retrieve? That would work a lot easier. See also reworked query.

Comment: Perfectly!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using the human language.

First query:

> Remove from `quiz_masters` all entries who have the active events at the `dow = 3`

Second query:

> Select entries from `quiz_masters` who have active events at the `dow <> 3`

There are not equal conditions in general. For example, if the quiz_masters have the active events at the dow = 3 and dow = 4 simultaneously then it will be absent in the first query but present in the second one. Yet another example: quiz_masters have no events at all. Then it will be present in the first and absent in the second query.

Mostly, such inconvenience is because the wrong usage of the `left (outer)` join: using the left joined table in the `where` clause you transforms it to the `(inner)` join. If `left join` worked properly - the first query would be empty and second one would return all active entries from the quiz_masters independently on the events BTW.